# How to draw a light effect over a texture on iPhone using UIKit/Quartz

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uikit, quartz-graphics

I have a scene with a background image (a lit room), and a black image (shadow) over that. I need to be able to move my finger over the background and reveal some parts of the scene, simulating a dim light source in a dark room.

My current approach was to generate a mask depending on the position of the touch, and then applying that mask to the shadow image. The problem is I'm generating a new mask and applying it every time I receive a touch event. It's a large image (800x600) and this causes the performance to go down and it increases a lot the memory usage, eventually crashing the game (I think I don't have any memory leaks, but that's not warrantied... anyway the performance itself isn't acceptable).

Can anyone think of a better approach (which doesn't involve using OpenGL ES -- that's not an option in this project) to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go with my comments above.

Maybe to get around the different shadow levels you could also have a grid of views (squares) between the image and the shadow view. each grid square has a different alpha opacity and when the spot is over  a grid square, the grid square's alpha opacity changes to 0. when the spot moves off the grid square it's alpha opacity changes back to it's default.

[image: room image with grid views and shadow view]

Answer (score 1):

Without more information it is a little difficult to know whether this approach will work in your case but what you could do is generate a single mask image, say, a radial alpha gradient and then apply an affine transform to it to shape it according to the touches. This can be used to simulate a torch/flashlight beam.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying right now. Sorry if I wasn't enough clear. :(

Comment: I think idz was saying not to generate a mask depending on the position of the touch, but to move an already generated mask depending on the position of the touch. Which is most quickly done using the UIView's transform property, which takes a CGAffineTransform.

Comment: @Tommy yes, that's what I meant. Thanks for clarifying. @Santiago did you get this working?

Answer (score 1):

I would try this: use one view with a custom drawRect implemetation: first draw the shadow image (in grayscale) then a bright spot image in white an alpha. And finally the background image in a 'multiply' blend mode.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, does the shadow has to be an image? Perhaps you could simply fill the shadow layer with a color and mask it then? This way the memory usage should be less and the effect should be nearly identical (if not exactly the same).

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, it needs to be an image... it has alpha and it shadows the background with different intensity in some places.

Comment: Oh, then I'm not quite sure what to do.

Comment: Not sure this is possible or make sense. How about the black image has a spot on it that is semi clear. That sees through to the view below with the main image. The black image is allowed to move as a whole and it is larger than the visable area of the game. it's view is allowed to clip outside of the main frame of the games view. Then when you put your finger on the spot and it appears only the spot is moving when actually it's the whole view.

Comment: To get the idea of the sort of movement I mean. On a iPad for example if you zoom right in to a safari page, you can move the very large page around with only a portion of it on screen.

Comment: I think that would work, but unfortunately he mentioned before that the shadow differs depending on the region of the underlying image (eg moving it around may have a undesired effect on the visuals).

Comment: @markhunte yeah, I think that's what I'm gonna try next... just fake it

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to generate a new mask on every touch move. Instead, let the mask be initialized once and manipulate it (reset it's frame) as needed upon touch events.